# a problem on system of equation in modulo classs

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$, $b$, $m$ and n be integers, $m$, $n$ positive,$ am + bn = 1$. Find an
integer $x$ (in terms of $a, b, m, n, p, q$) so that
$$x ≡ p (\mod m)$$
$$x ≡ q (\mod n)$$
where $p$ and $q$ are given integers.

---

I am completely stuck on this.how can I able to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This is chinese remaindering theorem:

From the first condition
$$
x= p + k\,m
$$
Substitute in the second to get
$$
p + k\, m \equiv q \mod n
$$
So you have to solve
$$
k \, m \equiv q-p \mod n
$$ to find $k$.

Once you have one $k = k_0$ then you can write
$$
k = k_0 + s\,n$$
and get
$$
x = p + k_0 \,m + s\,m\,n$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $x=(bn)p+(am)q$. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yeah, tried to remember this clean approach but couldn't write it out. +1

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $x$ which satisfies $x=p+km = q + \ell n$ for some integers $k,\ell$. This means you want to solve $p-q = km - \ell n$ for some $k, \ell$ integers. You already have $a$ and $b$ such that $am + bn = 1$. Multiplying this through by $p-q$, 
$$
( (p-q)a )m - ( (q-p) b) n = p-q.
$$
Let $k = (p-q)a$ and $\ell = (q-p)b$, so that $p+km = q + \ell n$. Then let $x = p+km$.

Hope that helps,